# Where is the GCC cross compiler for Xeon phi located?

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, xeon-phi

I found two binaries of compilers located as follows -

```
/usr/linux-k1om-4.7/bin/x86_64-k1om-linux-gcc
```

and

```
/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/bin/k1om-mpss-linux/k1om-mpss-linux-gcc
```

I have been able to compile a simple test program using both of them and successfully run the executable on xeon phi.

Are these two the same ? Why are they in different locations ? What is the naming convention behind them ?

EDIT: result of `*gcc -v`. It is the same for both except `$COLLECT_GCC`.

`Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/bin/k1om-mpss-linux/k1om-mpss-linux-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/libexec/k1om-mpss-linux/gcc/k1om-mpss-linux/4.7.0/lto-wrapper
Target: k1om-mpss-linux
Configured with: /sandbox/build/tmp/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-mpsssdk-linux/gcc-cross-canadian-k1om-4.7.0+mpss3.5.1-1/gcc-4.7.0+mpss3.5.1/configure --build=x86_64-linux --host=x86_64-mpsssdk-linux --target=k1om-mpss-linux --prefix=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr --exec_prefix=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr --bindir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/bin/k1om-mpss-linux --sbindir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/bin/k1om-mpss-linux --libexecdir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/libexec/k1om-mpss-linux --datadir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/share --sysconfdir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/etc --sharedstatedir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/com --localstatedir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/var --libdir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/lib/k1om-mpss-linux --includedir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/include --oldincludedir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/include --infodir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/share/info --mandir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/share/man --disable-silent-rules --disable-dependency-tracking --with-libtool-sysroot=/sandbox/build/tmp/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-mpsssdk-linux --with-gnu-ld --enable-shared --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-threads=posix --disable-multilib --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --enable-symvers=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-pch --program-prefix=k1om-mpss-linux- --enable-target-optspace --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-bootstrap --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --with-system-zlib --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-cheaders=c_global --with-local-prefix=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/k1om-mpss-linux/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/k1om-mpss-linux/usr/include/c++ --with-build-time-tools=/sandbox/build/tmp/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/k1om-mpss-linux/bin --with-sysroot=/opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/k1om-mpss-linux --with-build-sysroot=/sandbox/build/tmp/tmp/sysroots/knightscorner --disable-libunwind-exceptions --disable-libssp --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap --with-mpfr=/sandbox/build/tmp/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-mpsssdk-linux --with-mpc=/sandbox/build/tmp/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-nativesdk-mpsssdk-linux --enable-nls --enable-__cxa_atexit
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.0 20110509 (experimental) (GCC)`

Comment: What are the results of "*gcc -v" for each?

Comment: Edited in the question. Same for both though.

Comment: Are the sha512 results the same? If so, then these are the same binary :-)

Comment: yup, its the same. I wonder why there are two copies of it installed.
Anyways, can you tell me why the build and host configs are different if its a cross compiler ?

Answer (score 0):

You should find that /usr/linux-k1om-4.7/bin/x86_64-k1om-linux-gcc is actually a symbolic link to /opt/mpss/3.5.1/sysroots/x86_64-mpsssdk-linux/usr/bin/k1om-mpss-linux/k1om-mpss-linux-gcc. So, quite literally, they are the same binary.

In /opt/mpss, everything is organized under an MPSS release number. The paths in /usr/linux-k1om-4.7 remain the same regardless of the MPSS release.

The naming does seem to have gotten a little out of hand - x86_64 is for the architecture the cross compiler runs on, k1om is for the architecture you are compiling for (k for knights - the current coprocessor is code named knights corner) and, of course, 4.7 is the compiler version.

My head is not particularly sharp today, so I don't quite follow the question about the build and host configs.

Edit - ah, I see your other post (32319745) and the explanation there about the build and host configs. That discussion is much farther along, so I shall silently slink over there to listen and learn.

Comment: yeah, basically I'm trying to install `gcc-4.7.0+mpss3.5.2` compiler from its source rather than using the pre-compiled cross compiler binary already provided by intel. I am trying to figure out the correct parameters to pass to the `configure` script.